# How to well adapt height and position of views in iOS without AutoLayout?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, layout, storyboard

I am building a view in Storyboard. I have three parts :

1) top : real-time camera view (adaptive height)

2) middle : small webview (fixed height)

3) bottom : some buttons (fixed height)

I would like to know how to properly make my interface in the storyboard for a compatibility with iPhone 4 or iPhone 5 screens.
My goal is to have the camera having a bigger part of the screen on iPhone 5 (or any bigger screen) and the webview and buttons to have the exact same height on any device.
I did it quite well with the AutoLayout feature. The only problem is that it is available since iOS6 and my app has to work from iOS5 and above.

My Storyboard has an 4' display and when I try to run it on a real device (iPhone 4S) all the bottom of the screen is cropped and I can't see my buttons. I really can't figure it out what is really the best and proper way to do it. For a such simple problem, I shouldn't build two different storyboards.

Maybe should I try to fix the height of the camera view programmatically, but this won't fix the problem of the bottom of the screen cropped on smaller screens (I should then modify the position programmatically).

You can see that I haven't a really nice solution to my problem. Could someone help me in how using well the tools in XCode for this case ?

Thanks

Comment: I would use autoresizing mask to position view.  Use contentMode property of view and use appropriate contentMode. Look at these autoresizingMasks provided by UIView https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#jumpTo_143. Note these content mode support bit masking, so you could pass more than one value for the same  view.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Do you know if it is possible to define relations between views ? Is it possible to set them consecutive ?

Comment: FWIW, I find it easier just to do the layouts programmatically in "viewWillLayoutSubviews" in the view controller.

Comment: UIViewContentMode and autoresizing works in relation to superview.  I dont think it is possible to lay view with relation between two adjacent view or views in the same hierarchy using autoresizing mask like autolayout does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

[Xcode 4.5: How do I fix my text views so they display properly in portrait and landscape mode on an iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143404/xcode-4-5-how-do-i-fix-my-text-views-so-they-display-properly-in-portrait-and-l/13143600#13143600)

I think this could fix your problem and if you are using Storyboards it makes it less difficult.