# Scale images and buttons of layout in Xcode

Tags: xcode, layout, storyboard

How can I stretch the height of buttons and images in Xcode 4.6.3 in Storyboard?

I have a simple navigation with some images and a few navigations buttons as per the images below. In the first image its displayed on iPhone 4 and on image 2 its on iPhone 5. As you can see the buttons are now looking a bit lost on the bigger display.

Can I stretch the buttons' height for the iPhone 5 in Storyboard? I have seen examples of using Autolayout but they all seem to do with orientation (switching from portrait to landscape).

Can what I need to do be done with Struts and Springs perhaps? I am unable to test at the moment as I only have access to Xcode once a week. Just want to have as much information for the next time I get to work on project.

iPhone 4 display
[image]

iPhone 5 display
[image]

Answer (score 0):

that's actually really easy to awnser! Just use autosizing. Here is what you need to do:

[Xcode 4.5: How do I fix my text views so they display properly in portrait and landscape mode on an iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143404/xcode-4-5-how-do-i-fix-my-text-views-so-they-display-properly-in-portrait-and-l/13143600#13143600)

Just play around with the inner cross and see what happens. You need to set the autosizing for every button if you want to resize them all.

Have a good one,

Noah